# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated always false in .net core when user id type changed from string to integer

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, claims

I have an asp.net core application using json web tokens for authentication, this worked fine when my user Id was a string, but stopped working after changing to an int.

My IdentityUser type was originally this

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
     //other properties...
}
```

I updated this;

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
     //other properties...
}
```

I changed my Startup configuration from this;

```
        services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Issuer = jwtIssuerOptions.Issuer;
            options.Audience = jwtIssuerOptions.Audience;
            options.SigningCredentials = jwtIssuerOptions.SigningCredentials;
        });


        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = jwtIssuerOptions.Issuer,

            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = jwtIssuerOptions.Audience,

            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = _signingKey,

            RequireExpirationTime = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(configureOptions =>
        {
            configureOptions.ClaimsIssuer = jwtIssuerOptions.Issuer;
            configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
            configureOptions.SaveToken = true;
        });

        // add identity
        var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(o =>
        {
            // configure identity options
            o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            o.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        });
        builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(IdentityRole), builder.Services);
        builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

To this;

```
    services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Issuer = jwtIssuerOptions.Issuer;
            options.Audience = jwtIssuerOptions.Audience;
            options.SigningCredentials = jwtIssuerOptions.SigningCredentials;
        });


        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = jwtIssuerOptions.Issuer,

            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = jwtIssuerOptions.Audience,

            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = _signingKey,

            RequireExpirationTime = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(configureOptions =>
        {
            configureOptions.ClaimsIssuer = jwtIssuerOptions.Issuer;
            configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
            configureOptions.SaveToken = true;
        });

        // add identity
        var builder = services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole<int>>(o =>
        {
            // configure identity options
            o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            o.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        });
        builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(IdentityRole<int>), builder.Services);
        builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I use a the following method to generate the token, this is unchanged between implementations.

```
    public async Task<string> GenerateEncodedToken(string userName, ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        var claims = new[]
     {
             new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userName),
             new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, await _jwtOptions.JtiGenerator()),
             new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, ToUnixEpochDate(_jwtOptions.IssuedAt).ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64),
             identity.FindFirst(JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol),
             identity.FindFirst(JwtClaimIdentifiers.Id)
         };

        // Create the JWT security token and encode it.
        var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: _jwtOptions.Issuer,
            audience: _jwtOptions.Audience,
            claims: claims,
            notBefore: _jwtOptions.NotBefore,
            expires: _jwtOptions.Expiration,
            signingCredentials: _jwtOptions.SigningCredentials);

        var encodedJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

        return encodedJwt;
    }
```

And finally this method is used to create the claims identity;

```
    public ClaimsIdentity GenerateClaimsIdentity(string userName, int id)
    {
        return new ClaimsIdentity(new GenericIdentity(userName, "Token"), new[]
        {
            new Claim(JwtClaimIdentifiers.Id, id.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer32),
        });
    }
```

User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is now always false when validating and the ClaimsIdentity appears to be empty of the information I saw before converting my AppUser from a string ID type to an int Id type.

The best theory I have so far is that the problem may be related to serialisation/deserialisation of the token values but I'm clutching at straws and have little idea how I might debug it.

What have I missed?

Comment: Have you checked the token using something like jwt.io?

Comment: Check [this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authentication-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core-web-api-with-json-web-tokens/), after login success, you could use the following code to add claims:`var authClaims = new List<Claim>{new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),};`, Then, add this claim to the JwtSecurityToken.

Comment: Besides, you could also check the following article to use JWT Authentication: [JWT Authentication In ASP.NET Core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/) and [JWT Authentication Tutorial with Example API](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/11/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking [Connor Low's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65441483/1446086) I supplied delegates to all the `JwtBearerOptions` events. None of these where hit, indicating that my setup was insufficient and that the authentication scheme I had configured was not being used at all.

I reverted to `addIdentityCore`

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(o =>
```

Although I could no longer specify that I was using `IdentityRole<int>` instead of the default like this;

```
var builder = services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole<int>>(o =>
```

This seemed to be unnecessary provided I had the following line;

```
builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(IdentityRole<int>), builder.Services);
```

With these changes in place authentication worked and the breakpoints I had added at Connor Low's suggestion were being hit.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing glaring at me in your code (it looks like the primary difference is you swapped from `AddIdentity` to `AddIdentityCore`?), but I find with JWT auth issues, it really helps to run the app in debug mode and add handlers for `JwtBearerEvents`.
Add this to your Startup `.AddJwtBearer` call:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
      // ... 

      // Add this at the end:
      options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
      {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
// Put a breakpoint here
          System.Console.WriteLine(context.Exception);
          return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
      };
    })
```

If you run in debug, will be able to inspect the `context.Exception`:

[image: Example Exception inspection]

This should give you a better explanation of why JWT authentication is failing.

Comment: Saved my life with that breakpoint!